# What is the book that has an abandoned DeSoto in it along with two raccoons?

Tags: identification-request

So recently I felt a slight pang of regret for not reading enough of this really interesting book I got from the library at age 9. The plot goes something like this:
1: There is this evil crocodile kisser
2: There are two raccoons living in a DeSoto car
3: Blueberry Pie!
4: Also I know this takes place in a rural area.

Comment: Is an "evil crocodile kisser" an evil person who kisses crocodiles, an evil crocodile who kisses, or a person who kisses evil crocodiles?

Comment: A person who kisses crocodiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[True Blue Scouts of Sugar Man Swamp](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16074339-the-true-blue-scouts-of-sugar-man-swamp) by Kathi Appelt

> Meet Bingo and J’miah, raccoon brothers on a mission to save Sugar Man
>   Swamp in this rollicking tale and National Book Award Finalist from
>   Newbery Honoree Kathi Appelt.
>
> Raccoon brothers Bingo and J’miah are the newest recruits of the
>   Official Sugar Man Swamp Scouts. The opportunity to serve the Sugar
>   Man—the massive creature who delights in delicious sugar cane and
>   magnanimously rules over the swamp—is an honor, and also a big
>   responsibility, since the rest of the swamp critters rely heavily on
>   the intel of these hardworking Scouts.
>
> Twelve-year-old Chap Brayburn is not a member of any such
>   organization. But he loves the swamp something fierce, and he’ll do
>   anything to help protect it.
>
> And help is surely needed, because world-class alligator wrestler
>   Jaeger Stitch wants to turn Sugar Man swamp into an Alligator World
>   Wrestling Arena and Theme Park, and the troubles don’t end there.
>   There is also a gang of wild feral hogs on the march, headed straight
>   toward them all.
>
> The Scouts are ready. All they have to do is wake up the Sugar Man.
>   Problem is, no one’s been able to wake that fellow up in a decade or
>   four…

It's the first result in Google Books for *raccoons DeSoto car*, cane sugar pie business is mentioned on the Goodreads reviews. And according to [The New York Times review](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.nytimes.com/2013/07/14/books/review/kathi-appelts-true-blue-scouts-of-sugar-man-swamp.amp.html) the wrestler's signature move is kissing the defeated reptile on the lips.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @BlackyDoge Please don't forget to accept this answer. You can click the checkmark on the left, below the voting buttons, to mark it as correct.